# Xamarin.iOS - Unable to load view controller from within another view controller

Tags: xamarin, view, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios, xib

I recently started developing using Xamarin, so I'm by no means an expert and have been stuck on this problem for a day or so now.

First of all, I am not using storyboards. I am creating my own custom views (xib) and loading them from code

I'm building a new Xamarin.iOS app and am attempting to load a view controller from within another view controller. Initially, I am loading the first controller from the AppDelegate like so:

```
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
        {
            window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
            appStartUpController = new AppStartUpController();
            window.RootViewController = appStartUpController;
            window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

            return true;
        }
```

This loads my AppStartUpController fine which is basically just a loading screen with a background image and loading animation while I make an API call in the background. Once the API call has completed, I want to load another view controller.

After the API call has completed, I attempt to load the next Controller like so:

```
            var controller = new CityPickerViewController();
            this.NavigationController.PushViewController(controller, false);
```

And here is my CityPickerViewController:

```
    public partial class CityPickerViewController : UIViewController
    {
        CityPicker_View v;
        public CityPickerViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
        }

        public CityPickerViewController ()
        {
        }
        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            v = CityPicker_View.Create();
            this.View = v;
        }

        public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear(false);
            UIImage i = UIImage.FromFile("citypickbackground.jpg");
            i = i.Scale(this.View.Frame.Size);

            this.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromPatternImage(i);
        }
    }
```

I'm probably missing something obvious here, but the CityPickerViewController will not load. If I put a break point within the code, the viewDidLoad / ViewWillAppear overrides never get hit.

I'm a rookie programmer and would definitely appreciate any tips on this.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is `this` in `this.NavigationController`? I don't see you ever adding a UINavigationController to the stack, and in that case navigationController property can return null: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621860-navigationcontroller

Comment: Hi , have you solved it ?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

Try `base.NavigationController.PushViewController(controller, true);` instead since you don't have a local navigation controller.

There could also be an issue in your CityPickerViewController, so try a different ViewController if that doesn't work.

Comment: when using `base.NavigationController.PushViewController(controller, false);` and I step through the code, it hangs on this line.  The AppStartUpController (which starts fine when launched through AppDelegate) has this Method: `public AppStartUpController():base(null,null)`.  In the CityPickerViewController, the base method is this `public CityPickerViewController () // :base(null, null)`.  I had to comment out the base(null,null) as this would cause the code to hang when attempting to instantiate a new CityPickerViewController.

Comment: Can you place a Exception catchpoint, and see what the message says when it gets there? Also is it working now?

Comment: IT appears as though the base.NavagationController is null as it's returning a Null Reference Exception.

Comment: Check your Storyboard to see if you have a "navigationController" in it?

Comment: I'm not using storyboards

Comment: Try just a `PushViewController(controller, true);` then

Comment: `PushViewController` does not exist in the current context. I tried creating a new `NavController` and push the view like so `NavController.PushViewController(new CityPickerController(), false);` which is used in another part of my code with success, however here it just stops executing code. No exceptions thrown, just doesn't load the view.  Also tried pushing a different view controller, which works in another part of code, but that also fails here as well.

Comment: "however here it just stops executing code. No exceptions thrown, just doesn't load the view." That sounds exactly like like it's because that part of the code is not being run on the UI Thread, do this: UIApplication.SharedApplication.InvokeOnMainThread(delegate
{
           NavController.PushViewController(new CityPickerController(), true);
});

Comment: I had already tried something similar by running the code inside a `MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread()` with no luck. I switched it to what you suggested, but it has the same result. No exceptions thrown, no new view.

Comment: Darn, could you share a reproduceable version of code so I can locally debug it?

Comment: I just got the new view to load by doing this: `var controller = new CityPickerViewController(); ShowViewController(controller, this);` I've seen no reference to `ShowViewController` in any of the Xamarin.iOS documentation I've read, I found this in the Apple dev docs.  I'm wondering if there is any reason why I shouldn't be presenting a view in this way?  I'm curious as I've not seen this as a suggestion in any of the xamarin resources I've read so far

Comment: Were you using a Split ViewController by any chance?

Comment: No, I wasn't using split